# Error writing reports and rerun file while running cucumber tests in parallel

Tags: selenium, java, cucumber

I am building an automation framework using selenium, cucumber and trying to run my cucumber test  cases in parallel. I am using the jvm.cucumber.parallel plugin for executing my test cases parallel. My POM file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>Sample-Cucumber</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<name>Sample-Cucumber</name>
<description>Sample Automation with Cucumber Implementation</description>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.3</cucumber.version>
    <extentreports.version>2.41.0</extentreports.version>
    <selenium.version>2.53.1</selenium.version>
    <cucumber.jvm.parallel.version>1.2.1</cucumber.jvm.parallel.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sitture</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-extentreport</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>win</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.chrome.path>${basedir}${file.separator}resources${file.separator}chromedriver.exe</webdriver.chrome.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>linux</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>!windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.chrome.path>resources${file.separator}chromedriver</webdriver.chrome.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.jvm.parallel.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateRunners</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <glue>src/test/java/com/cucumber/stepdefinitions/</glue>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                    <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features/</featuresDirectory>
                    <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
                    <format>json,html</format>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                    <tags>"~@ignore"</tags>
                    <filterFeaturesByTags>true</filterFeaturesByTags>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Increase Fork Count to increase parallel execution count.
                Currently it is set to 5 which means 5 runners will run in parallel-->
                <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
               <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My runner files looks like this

```
package com.cucumber.runner.sample1;

import com.sitture.ExtentFormatter;
import com.tools.Constants;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = true,features = {     "classpath:features/Featureset1/" },
    glue = { "com.cucumber.stepdefinitions" },
    plugin = { "com.sitture.ExtentFormatter","pretty",
    "html:target/cucumber-reports",
    "json:target/cucumber.json",
    "rerun:target/rerun.txt" },
    tags={"~@skip"})
public class SampleRunner1IT {

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {

    //ExtentFormatter.initiateExtentFormatter();

    ExtentFormatter.initiateExtentFormatter(new File(Constants.RESOURCES_PATH+"Reports.html"),false);
    ExtentFormatter.loadConfig(new File(Constants.RESOURCES_PATH
            + "extent-config.xml"));

     //ExtentFormatter.addSystemInfo("Browser", "Chrome");
    ExtentFormatter.addSystemInfo("Selenium", "v2.53.1");

    Map<String, String> systemInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

    systemInfo.put("Cucumber", "v1.2.5");
    systemInfo.put("Extent Reports", "v2.41.1");
    ExtentFormatter.addSystemInfo(systemInfo);
}
}
```

I have multiple similar runner files which use the same pattern except the path for feature files for *features* under *@CucumberOptions*

The problem is that when I do *mvn clean install* or *mvn clean test* it keeps overwriting the Reports.html file and also my rerun.txt file is overwritten.

I am relatively new to cucumber automation framework would like to run my cucumber test is parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can define separate HTML report generation folder for each feature file but I would suggest try to use CI and cucumber report plugin which will ease your job, see [`cucumber-reporting`](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting).